# How to prevent jQuery from changing href attriute on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I have a collection of anchor tags, which look like so:

```
<a href='#123'></a>
```

I use the `#123` as an id, which I supply to an AJAX call. I make the call on click of a link. After a link is clicked, besides the displaying of the results of the AJAX call, two things happen:

1. the url in the address bar gets the hash like so: `www.localhost.com/foo#123`.
2. The `href` attribute of the clicked link gets changed from `#123` to the AJAX address `www.localhost.com/bar#123`. If I don't make an AJAX call (for test purposes), then it changes to the current url in the address bar: `www.localhost.com/foo#123`.

If I use `event.preventDefault`, than both of these things don't happen. I want to keep 1. (changing of the hash value in the address bar), but I don't won't to keep the value of the `href`, as otherwise, a subsequent click on the same link results in an error.

How can I do this?

### My code

I will include a simplified version of my code, which still produces the same effect.

```
makeAjaxCall = (brandId) ->
  alert 'OK'

$ ->
  $('.box-trigger').on 'click', (e) ->
    makeAjaxCall($(this).attr('href'))
```

This code gets loaded on page `www.localhost.com/foo`. If I click on the link, than I gen an alert with 'OK', the address changes to `www.localhost.com/foo#123` and the `href` of the link also changes to `www.localhost.com/foo#123`.

### Clarification regarding `foo` and `bar`

In the `makeAjaxCall` function, if I really make an ajax call to the url `www.localhost.com/bar`, then the `href` changes to `www.localhost.com/bar#123`. However, I removed the Ajax call to try to debug the problem. In that case the href changes to the current url, in this case `www.localhost.com/foo#123`.

### Solution

I ended up using `event.prevenDefault` + manually appending the hash to the address bar url like so:

```
$ ->
  $('.lightbox-trigger').on 'click', (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    makeAjaxCall $(this).attr('href')
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href')
```

Comment: add your jquery code

Comment: why don't you use data attribute instead of href like this  <a href=''" data-id="#123" ></a>

Comment: O.K., but it's CoffeeScript, I hope that's not a problem.

Comment: I assume you are modifying some code that you did not write, or have copied and pasted a script from somewhere else?  We need to see more of the code to tell what is making the changes you are talking about.  The behaviour of adding the `#` is normal for anchor links, but not the change from `foo` to `bar`

Comment: The #2 behavior of changing the href seems odd... and definitely not default behavior.

Comment: O.K., you all say it's not normal to change the `href`. I will try to investigate if any other code triggers the behavior.

Comment: Just don't use href... Seriously, why do you? Optimus is right, use another attribute, problem solved.

Comment: At `2.` you say it changes to `bar#123`, at the end of your question you say it changes to `foo#123`. Is `bar` a typo?

Comment: @t.niese I clarified my question.

Comment: @AlexPopov for this you need to use a ***MV*** frameworks like ember, angularjs etc.

Comment: @Optimus, @Jeremy Thille I use the `href` element, as I initiate some JS, based on the value of the hash upon page loan. What's more I need to be able to send direct links to people, so that these events can be triggered automatically when they load the page.

Comment: @AlexPopov I don't think that the attribute itself will change. But for the `href` property (the actual computed `href`)  the `#123` is equal to `www.localhost.com/foo#123` so there is nothing wrong about this. To the change to `bar#123`, does the URL also change to `bar` then (does the `makeAjaxCall` make use of  `pushState`?)

Comment: @t.niese, no the url doesn't change. That's a very basic AJAX call, which just takes the returned html and puts it in a div on the page. So the url in the address bar stays the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution suggestion 1**

I would use the data parameter, as suggested by Optimus in the comments. Like this:

**HTML**

```
<a class="box-trigger" data-id="#123"></a>
```

*Note:* I don't have the `href` parameter at all, this is because we don't want the URL to be affected at all, right? It's an AJAX call after all. (This will, however make most browsers not recognise the `<a>` tag as a link. It will lose its "link styling" as it where. You can easily simulate this by simply styling it using CSS.)

**CoffeeScript**

```
makeAjaxCall = (brandId) ->
  alert 'OK'

$ ->
  $('.box-trigger').on 'click', (e) ->
    makeAjaxCall($(this).data('id'))
```

*Note:* I have never used CoffeeScript, so this is just a guess.

**Solution suggestion 2**

If you, for some reason wish to have the ID as an anchor inside the `href`, you could have a look at the JQuery [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) function. This might just stop the URL from changing and all other behaviour you're experiencing.